# Break mode in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I tried to apply a font from the resourse but when I start up the program, Visual Studio will enter me to the break mode.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text

Dim customfont As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + "\Font.ttf", My.Resources.kenvector_future_thin, True)
customfont.AddFontFile(Application.StartupPath + "\Font.ttf")
Button1.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 20)
RadioButton1.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 14)
RadioButton2.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 14)
RadioButton3.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 14)
RadioButton4.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 14)
RadioButton5.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 14)
Label1.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 12)
GroupBox1.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 14)
GroupBox2.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 14)
Button1.Cursor = New Cursor(ms)
```

Comment: Well, apparently it does, yes. So, what's your exact question and what did you try?

Comment: I tried to change the application's font with .ttf file in resources

Answer (score 0):

Double check what your path is: Application.StartupPath 
Ensure that Visual Studio has access to that file and that file exists. 
Your error is telling you that you have a AccessViolationException. Right click on the file you are trying to use in Vb.Net and check within the properties of the file that it does not have permission rights associated with it.

Comment: An [**`AccessViolationException`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown when the application tries to access corrupted memory or protected memory that it does not have permission to read/write to. It is _**not**_ a result of being denied access to a file (in such event an [**`UnauthorizedAccessException`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx) is thrown).